# Python3 and Sublime Text 4 - building with no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext

When I run

```
print("Hello")
```

in my computer terminal it works fine, but when I run the same code in sublime it says "building" at the bottom but then nothing appears in the terminal. I created a build system for python3 and ran it through a script checker so I know it works. I made sure the build was not set to syntax and I made sure my save file wasn't dirty. I don't get an error message it just says building and then nothing comes up.

Comment: Have you saved the file first as a python program (e.g. "Hello.py")?  I just tried that out and it would not execute the command until it was saved as a python file.  After it was saved and I pressed "Ctrl-B" it ran and displayed "Hello".

Comment: Yes it's already saved as a .py file.

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure what else to add.  Perhaps this link might provide some ideas.  [Sublime](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-not-executing-my-py-files/51442)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post your build system.

Comment: In addition to what MattDMo mentioned, make sure you're not using a variant named `Syntax Check`; that variant only checks your code for errors but does not actually run it. If the build you created is based off of the one that ships with Sublime, it could have such a variant.